# Sum of sales for last 30days per user with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get new df column named as 'sales_30d_lag' with aggregated sales of last 30 days from last purchase date per user_id.  I know how to get the 30 days lag see below for my code but that won't resolve the issue since it is a fixed date.

| user_id | purchase_date | product | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/21 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 1/1/21 | A | 1 |

```
max_date = max(df['purchase_date'])
df['30d_lag']= pd.to_datetime(df['max_date']) - pd.to_timedelta(30)
```

I have also used a different approach but that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas how to get this column?

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime(df['max_date'])
end_date = start_date - pd.to_timedelta(30)
df_30d_lag = df[df['purchase_date'].between(start_date, end_date)].groupby('user_id').agg({'sales':'sum'}).rename(columns={'sales':'sales_30d_lag'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use combination of `isin` and `pd.date_range` functions.

Here's an example:

```py
start_date = pd.to_datetime(df['max_date'])
end_date = start_date - pd.to_timedelta(30)

30_d_df = df[df['datetime_col'].isin(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D'))]

# Once the filtration is complete you can use your normal groupby function 
30_d_df.groupby('user_id').agg({'sales':'sum'})
```

**NOTE:** For this function to work you need to have `datetime_col` in datetime (if it already isn't in it).

Comment: thanks for the answer. but for some reason I still get a TypeError : Cannot convert input. Even though all three attributes 'start_date', 'end_date' and df['date_col'] are in datetime64[ns] -- any thoughts?